# What would be the correct mount options for a separated btrfs /home partition in /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, mount, btrfs

After I read a bit about [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) I figured out it has many features I would like to use in the future, like snapshots, compression, defrag, enhancemence for SSD drives and so on. So I decided to acutally give that a try.

I converted my Ext4 home directory to Btrfs like this:

```
btrfs-convert /dev/mapper/system-home
```

Now the next tasks would be to create a propper entry for the `/etc/fstab` which currently still looks like this.

```
/dev/mapper/system-home /home ext4 nosuid,noexec,usrquota,grpquota 0 2
```

I am not quite sure about the `noexec` and the `nosuid` option. Does Btrfs understand these options? What would be the correct mount options for the Btrfs filesystem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is:

`/dev/mapper/system-home /home btrfs defaults 0 2`

- "btrfs" instead of ext4
- "defaults" says to use the default options.  Many people don't know that you don't *have* to specify mount options for every file system.

My personal preference for btrfs is this:

`/dev/mapper/system-home /home btrfs noatime,nodiratime,compress=lzo 0 2`

which are:

- noatime (**no a**ccess **time**): don't keep a time stamp every time a file is read; only time stamp when a file is changed.  (Most people don't even know that there is a file access time stamp, and most people don't need it, so don't waste resources writing to the disk when you are only reading something.)
- nodiratime (**no dir**ectory **a**ccess **time**): same thing for directories.
- compress=lzo : compress files using the lzo compression method.  LZO is fast, and the compression is invisible, so this is a big win for text files.

Comment: yeah thanks man. i did know about the noatime option but as you said i think i do not really need it. i simply checked and at least noexec also works with btrfs. the lzo compression i will test.

Comment: The last integer of the fstab entry should be a ```0``` because Btrfs does not do a file system check on boot.

Comment: In my experience, because Btrfs does not do a file system check on boot, it doesn't matter what the last integer is in the fstab entry.  It can be a 0, or a 2, or anything--  it is ignored at boot time from what I've seen.

Comment: I've read several places that `noatime` implies `nodiratime`; is there a need to specify both? Personal preference, but I get it appears "not to matter", but putting in 2 just because still seems weird. The wiki [says to use zero](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What.27s_the_difference_between_btrfsck_and_fsck.btrfs) and that `fsck.btrfs` will get called if `pass` is non-zero. That said, it looks to not do anything and just refer you to look into `btrfs check`.

Comment: I think you've found clarifications of details that weren't as well-known when this question was answered two years ago. Good work; thanks for sharing!  On noatime vs nodiratime, it is still unclear to me if that is the same for all filesystem types, or if it varies. I find direct statements about it for ext3/4 and xfs, but I haven't seen btrfs docs address it directly. There is no harm, at least, in specifying both. :-)

Comment: Suggesting explicit compress mount option is dangerous, some directories should not be compressed like /var it leads to huge performance loss (database files, libvirt VM images). It's much better just to mark /usr/ to be compressed as most of the files which don't change are stored there in modern distros.

Comment: I think "dangerous" is an exaggeration; it depends completely on your workload.  A write-intensive OLTP database or VM image probably shouldn't be on a COW file system to begin with.  A mostly-read reporting database can benefit greatly from the compression. It all depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

> > I am not quite sure about the noexec and the nosuid option.

If you mean you're not sure what these options mean they are both security or system protection measures-

1. **nosuid** prevents a program (executable) that is loaded from that  mount/ filesystem from running with "set User ID" privileges. Setuid programs are typically utilities that need to run with high (maybe root) privileges, even if they are started by ordinary users.
2. **noexec** prevents the execution of any programs from that mount point (and therefore it renders the nosuid redundant).

Letting users upload or write their own programs from their own home directories obviously involves some risk to the system. Letting users run setuid programs involves much more risk. Using both options is a belt+braces approach to avoiding that risk.

Answer (score 1):

In the `mount` manpage, both `exec`/`noexec` and `suid`/`nosuid` are listed under the sections **Filesystem-independent mount options**.  This means that they are implemented at or above the VFS layer in the kernel, and don't require any support from the filesystem.

The short answer is that both `noexec` and `nosuid` will continue to work exactly the same as they did for your `ext4` filesystem.

You might want to also consider adding `nodev` to the options.